# check if a string's first 16 char is a number

Tags: asp.net

I'm storing some files in database which has filename like **1839341255115211butterflies.jpg**.I need to show this filename to the user as **butterflies.jpg**.I need to remove the first 16 digit and then show the filename.Added to it I also have few filenames which don't have this 16digit addition prior to the filename.Now my question is how do I identify if this string has 16digit numeric value prior to the filename, based on it remove the 1st 16digit and display just the filename.  I'm aware of how to remove the first 16digit and retrive the filename but  need help on how to identify  a string that has 16digit.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression looks like a good fit here:

```
^[0-9]{16}
```

The above will match on strings that start with 16 digits (0 to 9).

Usage:

```
if(Regex.Match(fileName, @"^[0-9]{16}").Success)
{
  fileName = fileName.Remove(0, 16);
}
```

Comment: @newuser1555 In oracle you can do something like `select * from files_table where regexp_like(file_name, ^[0-9]{16}.*\.jpg)`.

Answer (score 1):

string.Remove will work quite nicely:

```
    var str = "1839341255115211butterflies.jpg";
    str = str.Remove(0, 16);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: OP did say that some strings do not start with 16 digits. OP is looking for a way to tell them apart.

Comment: @Oded: Good point. Looks like my snippet needs to go inside your snippet ;-) +1

Comment: Yeah. Though you could skin this cat with Regex alone.

Answer (score 0):

With Linq:

remove all digits at the beginning until 16 digits:

```
string file = "1839341255115211butterflies.jpg";
string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
fileName = new string(fileName.Where((c, i) => i >= 17 || !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
file = fileName + extension;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/gI3Gq9)

**Edit**: If you just want to know if the first 16 chars are digits, it's easier and more readable:

```
bool startsWith16Digits = file.Take(16).All(Char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: Hmm. Certainly an example for LINQ is not for everything ;)

Comment: @Oded: Note that it's easier (and probably more redable) to achieve just what your regex does: `fileName.Take(16).All(c => Char.IsDigit(c));`

Comment: Thank you guys.@Oded: Your solution was the one I was looking for.Thank you So much.